# i am getting error while inserting data into mysql using php(pdo)

Tags: php, pdo

```
<?php
      $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO slider(ZSLIDE_SLIDER_NO, ZSLIDE_TITLE, ZSLIDE_IMG, ZSLIDE_IMG_ALT, ZSLIDE_LINK, ZSLIDE_LINK_TARGET,ZSLIDE_COUNTRY_ID, ZSLIDE_STATUS) VALUES(:ZSLIDE_SLIDER_NO, :ZSLIDE_TITLE, :ZSLIDE_IMG, :ZSLIDE_IMG_ALT, :ZSLIDE_LINK, :ZSLIDE_LINK_TARGET,:ZSLIDE_COUNTRY_ID :ZSLIDE_STATUS)");

     $is_success = $stmt->execute(array(":ZSLIDE_SLIDER_NO" => $slider_no, ":ZSLIDE_TITLE" => $title, ":ZSLIDE_IMG" => $thumbimg_filename, ":ZSLIDE_IMG_ALT" => $alt, ":ZSLIDE_LINK" => $link, ":ZSLIDE_LINK_TARGET" => $link_target, ":ZSLIDE_COUNTRY_ID"=>$country_id, ":ZSLIDE_STATUS" => $activate_status));

        // print_r($is_success);exit;
        if($is_success)
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Added Successfully.');</script>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Failed to add.');</script>";
        }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Oh, I accidentally rejected @Option edit suggestion, but it should be accepted

Comment: you are not binding parameters to placeholders

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

Please correctly bind values to your parameters in the query.
Like this :

```
$stmt->bindParam(':ZSLIDE_SLIDER_NO', $slider_no, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

You were trying to bind the parameters while executing the query. This is not possible, so you have to bind the parameters before executing the query.

Also, As Alon Eitan correctly pointed out, you forgot to include a comma between your last two placeholders in your statement `:ZSLIDE_COUNTRY_ID :ZSLIDE_STATUS`

Comment: that is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: If you're posting an answer, make sure you **answer the question** - They bind the parameters in the `execute` and missed `,` here: `:ZSLIDE_COUNTRY_ID :ZSLIDE_STATUS`

Comment: @RamRaider Detailed the answer, and added what Alon Eitan pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You missed comma here

```
:ZSLIDE_COUNTRY_ID :ZSLIDE_STATUS
```

correct:

```
:ZSLIDE_COUNTRY_ID,:ZSLIDE_STATUS
```

Answer (score -1):

Possible errors:

- check correct columns in DB for table `slider`
- Check last error of SQL:

> ```
> else {
>   echo "< script>alert('Failed to add: " . $db->errorInfor() . ");</ script>";
> }
> ```

#### problem

In binding, you have missin `,`:

> :ZSLIDE_COUNTRY_ID :ZSLIDE_STATUS